# JSON:Circular Reference Error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm trying to make a RESTful API with rails. When I try `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/projects.json?token=kS8xi7YzaUDEmbmi9XL6` I get a error:

```
Parameters: {"token"=>"kS8xi7YzaUDEmbmi9XL6"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" =   'kS8xi7YzaUDEmbmi9XL6' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError (object references itself):
app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

### The base controller

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Base
 before_filter :authenticate_user

respond_to :json


 private
  def authenticate_user
    @current_user = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:token])
    unless @current_user
      respond_with( {:error => "Token is invalid."} )
    end
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user
  end
end
```

### The main controller

```
class Api::V1::ProjectsController < Api::V1::BaseController 
 def index
   respond_with(Project.for(current_user))
  end
 end
```

On trying in the console, `User.find_by_authentication_token("kS8xi7YzaUDEmbmi9XL6")` gives the correct user. When sending this same token via params it goes into that cryptic error. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I needed to do fix the controller action to

```
def index
  respond_with(Project.for(current_user).all)
end
```